# Regroup common items values in the same array using Powershell

Tags: powershell

Please I need help to do this in PowerShell using array.
I have an array similar to $a below:

```
$a = @('**ABC**:XYZ','**LMN**:PQR','**ABC**:RST','YJQ:PRS','**LMN**:SDK')
```

I want to change the `$a` array to `$b`:

```
$b = @('**ABC**:XYZ,RST','**LMN**:PQR,SDK','YJQ:PRS')
```

The idea is that all items that have common values before ":" should be combined in the format like "common_value:x,y,z" but others without common values should be left alone. Any hint or solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty example:

```
    $a = @('**ABC**:XYZ','**LMN**:PQR','**ABC**:RST','YJQ:PRS','**LMN**:SDK')
    
    $b=
    $a | 
    Select-ObJect @{Name = 'Name'; Expression = { $_.Split(':')[0]  }},
    @{Name = 'Group'; Expression = { $_.Split(':')[1] }} |
    Group-Object -Property Name |
    ForEach-Object{ "'$($_.Name):$($_.Group.Group -join ',')'"}
    
    $b = $b -join ','
    
    $b
```

Output:

```
'**ABC**:XYZ,RST','**LMN**:PQR,SDK','YJQ:PRS'
```

This also works:

```
    $a = @('**ABC**:XYZ','**LMN**:PQR','**ABC**:RST','YJQ:PRS','**LMN**:SDK')
    
    $b =
    $a | Group-Object {$_.Split(':')[0]} |
    ForEach-Object{
        "'$($_.Name):$(($_.Group.Split(':') | Group-Object { $Global:i % 2; $Global:i++ })[1].Group -join ',')'"
    }
    
    $b = $b -join ','
    $b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$b = $a | ConvertFrom-String -Delimiter ':' | 
     Group-Object P1 | 
     ForEach-Object { "$($_.name):$($_.group.P2 -join ',')" }
```

- [`ConvertFrom-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-string?view=powershell-7.1) splits each input string at ':', creating an object with properties `P1` and `P2` for part before and after ':'
- [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.1) groups by part before ':'
- Using [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.1) we build the result string from part before ':' with part(s) after ':'

Comment: Very nice, I didn't think to use `ConvertFrom-String`.

Comment: @Steven I just learned about it, looking for a more elegant way than `-split` operator. 

Comment: Thank you Steven. This worked nicely apart from the delimiter "," that was not included.